# How can I add rows in multiple tables at once?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, phpmyadmin

I've made a java program in netbeans which executes different queries in my database. I have a problem when I add data in the tables. It inserts data in the first 2 tables but not in the third one too. Here's the code:

```
String sql="INSERT INTO  `adresa` (`ID` ,`TARA` ,`JUDET` ,`LOC` ,`CPOSTAL` ,`STRADA` ,`NR` ,`BLOC` ,`SC` ,`APT`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, ID.getText());
    pst.setString(2, tara.getText());
    pst.setString(3, judet.getText());
    pst.setString(4, loc.getText());
    pst.setString(5, cpostal.getText());
    pst.setString(6, strada.getText());
    pst.setString(7, nr.getText());
    pst.setString(8, bloc.getText());
    pst.setString(9, sc.getText());
    pst.setString(10, apt.getText());
    pst.execute();

String sql2="INSERT INTO  `pbd`.`buletin` (`CNP` ,`DATAN` ,`SEX` ,`SERIENRB` ,`DATAEMIT` ,`DATAEXP`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);";
pst.setString(1, CNP.getText());
pst.setString(2, datan.getText());
pst.setString(3, sex.getText());
pst.setString(4, serienrb.getText());
pst.setString(5, dataemit.getText());
pst.setString(6, dataexp.getText());
pst.executeBatch();

String sql3="INSERT INTO  `pbd`.`persoana` (`ID` ,`CNP` ,`NUME` ,`PRENUME` ,`NATIONALITATE` ,`VIU`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);";
pst.setString(1, ID.getText());
pst.setString(2, CNP.getText());
pst.setString(3, nume.getText());
pst.setString(4, prenume.getText());
pst.setString(5, nationalitate.getText());
pst.setString(6, viu.getText());
pst.executeBatch();
```

And here are the tables information:

[image]

I think the queries are wrong or the concept of the tables but I am not sure. Please tell me what do you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your code for sql2 and sql3 as

```
pst.close();
String sql2="INSERT ...
pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
...
pst.executeUpdate();

pst.close();
String sql3="INSERT ...
pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql3);
...
pst.executeUpdate();
```

executeBatch is irrelevant in this case, it can only be used for different parameter sets of the same SQL.